# Include JWT in HTTP Headers when making ajax call

Tags: angularjs, rest, restangular, jwt

I am writing an angular app and have been asked to store a Json Web Token in a cooke and supply it in the HTTP headers with every request.

Does anybody know how to attach HTTP headers and what the header should be called?

I'm using Restangular if that changes anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restangular readme has a FAQ called 
[I need to send one header in EVERY Restangular request, how do I do this](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/blob/master/README.md#i-need-to-send-one-header-in-every-restangular-request-how-do-i-do-this), which seems to match your question, pretty much.

If it's a cookie, then the header is called "Cookie". The value would be `<cookie-name>=<jwt-value>` where `<cookie-name>` is whatever the server wants the JWT cookie to be called.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a read. I'm not intending to attach the cookie, I'm going to extract the JWT and just send that in it's own header. I was just wondering if there is a "best practice" for what to call it.

Comment: If you're writing the server-side yourself, and there's not standard involved, then you can call the header anything you want really. If it's something like an access token, then you would probably use the "Authorization" header.